# How can I conditionally import/export libraries in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a file that I want to be able to use both on the server using node.js as well as on the  browser.

I conditionally imported an external library using this line. On the browser, I assume that XRegExp is already defined.

```
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') XRegExp = require('xregexp').XRegExp;
```

and I conditionally exported the code using this line

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && !module.exports) module.exports = ret;
```

How can I do the same thing in TypeScript without the compiler complaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
declare var require;
declare var XRegExp;
declare var ret;

if (typeof require !== 'undefined') XRegExp = require('xregexp').XRegExp;
if (typeof this.module !== 'undefined' && !this.module.exports) this.module.exports = ret;
```